# How to mock a class exported from a third party library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

We are writing some unit tests for React components using Jest and I've come across an issue that I can't seem to wrap my brain around. We need to mock a single class from a third party library that exports a number of classes. But we don't want to mock ALL of the classes, just the one.

```
// third-party-library
export ClassA;
export ClassB;
export ClassC;
```

```
// hooks.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ClassB } from 'third-party-module';

export const myHook = () => {
  const [mystate, setMystate] = useState({});
  const classB = new ClassB();
  // ...implementation...
  return mystate;
};
```

```
// our-test-case.js
import { myHook } from '../hooks.js';

// --- This isn't quite what I want (ClassA and ClassC are mocked)
// jest.mock('third-party-library');
// ---

// --- This also does not appear to work (ClassA and ClassC are still mocked)
// jest.mock('third-party-library', () => ({
//   __esModule: true,
//   ClassB: class {
//     ...mock implementation..
//   }
// });
// ---

it('mock ClassB', () => {
  const mystate = myHook();
  // ...implementation...
});
```

I only want to mock `ClassB` in this example. I want to keep `ClassA` and `ClassC` the same (there are other tests in this file that depend on it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I found the golden nugget after more digging through jest documentation and trial and error. Here's the final test case code:

```
// our-test-case.js
import { myHook } from '../hooks.js';

jest.mock('third-party-library', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('third-party-library'), // This is the golden nugget.
  ClassB: class {
    ...mock implementation..
  }
});

it('mock ClassB', () => {
  const mystate = myHook();
  // ...implementation...
});
```

Reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks